# How to implement next and previous button with this code?

Tags: android, onclick, switch-statement, android-mediaplayer

I have code which has a switch implementation to implement the required output. Now I need this implementation has a next and previous buttons too. But i don't know simple solution, starter for this. Here is my code:

```
   private MediaPlayer clipSetup(int i){
    switch (i){
        case 1:
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.al01);
            mediaPlayer.start(); 
            break;
        case 2:
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.al02);
            mediaPlayer.start();    
            break;
        case 3:
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.al02);
            mediaPlayer.start();
            break;
        }
        return mediaPlayer;
     }
```

Now looking on this code, i want i have OnClick buttons implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you.

```
int current=0;
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btn_back:
            current++;
            break;
        case R.id.btn_next:
            if(current<=0)
                current=2;
            else
            current--;
            break;
    }
    clipSetup(current%3+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to implement remote buttons, use the code below.

```
        int keycode = event.getKeyCode();

        if(event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            return true;
        }

            switch (keycode){
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT :
                    if(videoType.equals(GENERAL)){
                        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                            rewindSurfacePlayer();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
                    if(videoType.equals(GENERAL)){
                        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                            fastForwardSurfacePlayer();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
                    if(videoType.equals(GENERAL)){
                        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                            showSurfaceControls();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
                    if(videoType.equals(GENERAL)){
                        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                            if(!vidPaused){
                                pauseSurfacePlayer();
                            }else {
                                playSurfacePlayer();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PROG_RED://rewind
                    if(videoType.equals(GENERAL)){
                        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                            rewindSurfacePlayer();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PROG_GREEN://forward
                    if(videoType.equals(GENERAL)){
                        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                            fastForwardSurfacePlayer();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE:
                    if(videoType.equals(GENERAL)){
                        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                            if(!vidPaused){
                                pauseSurfacePlayer();
                            }else {
                                playSurfacePlayer();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_STOP:
                    stopVideo();
                    break;
                case 23://play/pause
                    if(videoType.equals(GENERAL)){
                        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                            if(!vidPaused){
                                pauseSurfacePlayer();
                            }else {
                                playSurfacePlayer();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_FAST_FORWARD:
                    if(videoType.equals(GENERAL)){
                        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                            fastForwardSurfacePlayer();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_REWIND:
                    if(videoType.equals(GENERAL)){
                        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                            rewindSurfacePlayer();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE:
                    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        pauseSurfacePlayer();
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY:
                    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        playSurfacePlayer();
                    }
                    break;
            }
```

This needs to go on the dispatchKeyEvent method btw. You could also do the handle of the back button there. No need to use onBackPressed method. If you are already using onBackPressed and want to use dispatchKeyEvent, delete your onBackPressed method.